# Google Compute health check regarding pods on Google Container Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

Does a health check concern a whole node or does it concern individual containers?

I have created my LoadBalancer service with `kubectl create -f web-service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: reaction-prod
  labels:
    name: reaction-prod
    app: reaction-prod
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: reaction-prod
    app: reaction-prod
```

The load balancer targets a port inside the running containers, I have learned by experiment.
If I add a health check to that load balancers target pool, does it automatically do the same? I found no way to configure that or get information about what it is doing.

How can I get statistics on that health check?

`gcloud compute http-health-checks describe` doesn't really give me much useful info.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/766347/gce-health-check-and-liveness-probe), the health checks of the Load Balancer are different from Kubernetes’ health checks.  That being said, a friendly way to monitor your PODs in GKE is by using [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html).